# Can I have different SSL certificate for each servlet?

Tags: java, android, servlets, ssl

Here is a snippet of the web.xml configuration in my GWT web application

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE web-app
    PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

      <web-app>

      <servlet>
       <servlet-name>firstServlet</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>com.test.server.First</servlet-class>
      </servlet>


      <servlet>
       <servlet-name>secondServlet</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>com.test.server.Second</servlet-class>
      </servlet>


      <servlet>
       <servlet-name>thirdServlet</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>com.test.server.Third</servlet-class>
      </servlet>

    </web-app>
```

Let's say :

- firstServlet is the entrypoint of every queries coming from browsers
- secondServlet is the entrypoint of every queries coming from an android app
- and thirdServlet is the entrypoint of every queries coming from an iOS app

Questions :

1 - Can I use different SSL Certificates (maybe self-signed) for secondServlet and thirdServlet without affecting firstServlet ? (This means firstServlet will accept http queries, secondServlet and thirdServlet will only accept httpS queries).

2 - How do I do that ? (Syntax needed for the related Servlets in the web.xml etc...)

Thank you,

Comment: I don't think you can; The certificate is made to authorize the entire host machine, not just the one application

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. See [What topics can I ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Web Apps Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @kolossus - There are some standards coming down that validates servers and their services, and not just servers. See, for example, [RFC 6125, Representation and Verification of Domain-Based Application Service Identity within Internet Public Key Infrastructure Using X.509 (PKIX) Certificates in the Context of Transport Layer Security (TLS)](http://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6125.txt). I don't know if Apache or nginx expose it, though. That's something to ask a server admin or web master.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traditionally there is only a single certificate on a single IP. So if you could make your web server to handle each servlet on its own IP address (which means also another hostname) you can do it. Example: you have a server at servlet1.example.com and another at servlet2.example.com and both servers have a different IP address, then you could have a different servlet with a different certificate on each of this servers, or you could also have one of the servers with no certificate.

With Server Name Indication there can be a multiple hostnames on the same IP address and each hostname can have its own certificate. But, it is not possible to have any hostname without certificate because they web server will listen on the same IP/port for SSL connections and decide only after it got the initial Hello from the client which certificate will be served. So if you have only few IP addresses, but can have a unique hostname per servlet you can do it with SNI. But any servlets which should have no certificate need to be served from a different IP address then the https servlets. Example: if you have servlet1.example.com, servlet2.example.com both sharing the same IP address, than you could have different certificates for each of the servers, if the client supports SNI (all recent browsers do, but IE8 does not). But you cannot make servlet1.example.com to SSL, while servlet2.example.com not, as long as both share the same IP address.

It is not possible to have certificates specific to the path of the URL, because the path is only known after the SSL handshake, e.g. after the certificate was already provided. Example: there is no way to have different certificates for `https://www.example.com/servlet1` and `https://www.example.com/servlet2` because they both share the same hostname and differ only by the path of the URL.

Comment: It is indeed possible. The server could initiate a re-handshake if it wants to send a different certificate depending on the path.

Comment: @EJP, that's true in principle, but all those different certs would certainly need to be valid for the same host name as initially requested (which seems a bit pointless).

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Steffen. Nevertheless, do you have a short practical example describing your concept ? The explanation seems a bit too technical for me.
Thank you in advance. Regards,

Comment: @user3793589: I hope the examples I just added help to understand the issue better.

Comment: @EJP: while it might be possible to change the certificate with a renegotiation I know of no server which supports to renegotiate to a new certificate based on the path of the URL. I'm also not sure that clients would accept a change to a certificate which does not match the original request. Do you have more information about this?

Comment: It *is* possible, no question about it. I don't know of any server that  does it, but I can imagine a Tomcat valve that does it in association with a custom HTTPS connector, or access to its KeyManager somehow. I don't see why the client would object, as long as both certificates passed hostname verification at the HTTPS level. SSL certainly wouldn't care as long as both certificates were trusted. @Bruno You would need such functionality if you were an ISP and wanted to provide a Tomcat with multi-hosting.

Comment: @EJP, I meant you can make a request to a specific path without knowing its host in advance, which is also the host you're going to make the initial query to. Say you want to get `http://example.com/webapp2`, you're first going to make the request to `example.com` anyway, whether `webapp1` or `webapp2` should present distinct certs doesn't really make sense. HTTPS's name verification doesn't handle this (even RFC 6125 doesn't say much about URI-type SANs, AFAIK). Renegotiation at that stage barely matters, since you'll always know the host name first anyway at least, from the URL.

Comment: Here the question is about distinguishing per user-agent, not path, but the problem is that same. Even if you used a generic HTTP `OPTIONS *` first, without any need for a path, the cert would still need to be valid for the host name of interest. The only way to indicate which cert to choose before any HTTP traffic is SNI, which only carries the server name, not the path or user agent, so no other criterion for choosing a cert beforehand can be used.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve that is a combination of application and web server configuration. Using **Apache2** as web-front with module **mod_rewrite**, you can configure this redirection. Then, in your application, you will need to have each Servlet answering (mapped) in a different URL.

Follows an example below, in the first block, HTTP port 80, it is re:

In apache, create a new conf file inside conf.d directory like this example:

```
<VirtualHost 10.0.0.199:80>
    (...)
    #redirect all to https
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^www\.yourdomain\.com [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^$
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)         https://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [L,R]
    (...)
    #redirect based on URI to https
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/servlet1\/
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [L,R=301]
    (...)
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 10.0.0.199:443>
    (...)
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^www\.yourdomain\.com [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^$
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)         https://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [L,R]
    (...)
</VirtualHost>
```

Have a look at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Quite correct but you don't need rewriting or redirection, just mod_proxy or mod_proxy_ajp.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @mchamati. Nevertheless, do you have a short practical example describing your concept ? The explanation seems a bit too technical for me. Thank you in advance. Regards

Comment: All these rewrites/reverse proxies happen after the certificate was sent. This is fine if you want to redirect to a different server, but not if you want to choose the cert beforehand.